# ReactJS error while multiple rendering

Tags: reactjs

> Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin
>   provided (‘null’) does not match the recipient window’s origin
>   (‘null’).

I have used CDN links in my program but it is showing this error. How to solve?